# If else statement for login validation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms, authentication

I have this login validation script in php/wordpress that I can't seem to get to work right. It works ok when the username and email are put in correct, and seems to work when the user puts the wrong password in but when the wrong username is put in the input fields disappear on the refresh of the page after submit.
I've beer round this for a couple of days, not all the time but I have tried multiple variations.
I think it comes down to the curly brackets placement.
I'm relatively new with php so forgive me if this question seems stupid or the solution is simple.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;  $result = $wpdb->get_results("select username, password from mytable, ARRAY_A);
 $requestLogin = isset($_POST['submitLogin']);


if($requestLogin){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

        foreach($result as $row)
            if($username == $row['username']){
                if($password == $row['password']){
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    print "Welcome back ". $username;
                    print ("<br /><a href='profilr.php'>Click here for your profile</a>");
                    print ("<p><a href='logout.php'>Click here to logout</a></p>");
            }
            if($password != $row['password']){
                    print ("<form method=post>
                        <table>
                        <tr><td><input type=text name=username /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type=password name=password /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type=submit value=Submit name=submitLogin /></td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </form>");
                        print "Wrong Password";
            }
        }
            }
            else{
                print ("<form method=post>
                        <table>
                        <tr><td><input type=text name=username /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type=password name=password /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type=submit value=Submit name=submitLogin /></td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </form>");
                print "Please enter your Username & Password";      
        }

?>
```

Comment: exactly why are you slurping the entire contents of your usertable into PHP and then looping on the results. that's the equivalent of driving to the grocery store, buying EVERYTHING in the store, hauling it home, and then throwing away everything except the candy bar you wanted.

Comment: If this is WordPress, why aren't you using the built in user management system? Implementing your own user management instead of using a perfectly good existing system is a bad idea. Especially when you're not familiar with best practices.

Comment: Sorry Marc B, I can't see what you mean, I'm only calling the username and password from mytable?

Comment: @Paul66: let's say you have 5000 users. you suck 5000 users+passes in your php client, pick through each, and throw away all but 4999. why not just have the DB filter for you? that's why you have a db. `select .. where username=$user`, basically.

Comment: The else clause at the end is run when `$requestLogin` is false, not when there is no match for the username. Use proper [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) to spot errors like this easyer.

Comment: Marc B this is the initial login and session page so it could be any one of the 5000 that is logging in. Anders, you could be onto something here, should I split it into, one for if the username and password is correct and verified (which works here already) and another $requestLogin if there is an error in the user input?

Comment: So after much testing and searching I have found this code which I am going to use, it's not perfect but it does the job:-

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


global $wpdb;  $result = $wpdb->get_results("select Id, username, password    from myTable WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password', ARRAY_A);

foreach($result as $row)
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
print "Hi " . $username . " you are now in the Members Area<br><br>";
print ("<a href='?page_profile.php'>Click here for your profile</a><br>");
print ("<a href='?page_id=login.php'>Click here to logout</a><br>");

}else{
    print ("<form method=post>
        <table>
        <tr><td><input type=text name=username /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type=password name=password /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type=submit value=Submit name=submitLogin /></td>    </tr>
        </table>
        </form>");
print "Please enter your correct Username & Password";  
        }
?>
```